# fill in UITableViewCell with JSONdata

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, alamofire

I am trying to display some json data inside my tableView cell, and parsed the json data.

But

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.contents.count
}
```

returning `0`

and as a result, I cannot display the data inside the `UITableViewCell` eventhough I have all my `JSON` data have been parsed and ready to be displayed.. .
how to fix it?

my response Model class and the rest of implementation are as follows:

1. Model classes for `json` response

```
// MARK: - TradingPairElement
class TradingPair: Entity {
    var id: Int?
    //var name: String?
    var quoteAsset: QuoteAsset?

   
}

enum QuoteAsset: String, Codable {
    case btc = "BTC"
    case krw = "KRW"
}


// MARK: - TickerByPair
class TickerByPair: Entity {
    var ask: Int?
    //var price: Double?
    //var volume: Double?
    var askVolume: Double?
    var bid: Int?
    var bidVolume: Double?
    var time: String?
   
}
```

And a wrapper `class` for the above two `class` 's contents:

```
class Entity: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var price: Double?
    var volume: Double?
}
```

and here is how i am getting the data from the api and assigning to my `self` variables:

```
    func APIcall() {
        ServerCommunicator.getPairs().done{ response -> Void in
            for keyPathParam in response {
                self.keyPathParam = keyPathParam.name
            }
            ServerCommunicator.getPair(with: self.keyPathParam).done{ ticker -> Void in
                for data in self.contents {
                    data.name = ticker.name
                    data.price = ticker.price
                    data.volume = ticker.volume
                    self.contents.append(data)
                }
            }.catch{(err) in
                print(err)
            }
        }.catch{(error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: When are you reloading the `tableView`?

Comment: oh, good question.. ) but i am having a crash already in   `numberOfRow` part of tableView.. .

Comment: What is the crash/error?

Comment: `self.contents.count` is `0`

Comment: Nope, that is not causing crash, something else is. Look for it or share the error message here.

Comment: or anything is wrong with my api call `func`? cuz i can see the `JSON response` in `console` but not in `tableViewCell`

Comment: seems like the `json response` contents and the `self.contents` contents are somehow not linked, cuz i can see the `response` coming from `api`, i mean it is already parsed in `console log`.. ..

Comment: `self.contents` is the variable of a class the response.contents is different.

Comment: Probably unrelated but `for data in self.contents {… self.contents.append(data)… }` makes no sense.

Comment: @vadian, lol.. yeah buddy.. I think so too.. I deleted that code snippet now.. . see, it is me again, with the same problem for days everyday.. i am just doin all the logic which comes to my mind.. . Actually, usually, I dont have much trouble with parsing json response, but this one just shook me.. .

Comment: @vadian, just let me know if you have a better logic for this piece of code.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if the API sends always all keys declare the properties non-optional and as constants and most likely you don't need a class and conformance to `Encodable`

```
struct Entity: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    let volume: Double
}
```

After getting the data from the server you have to create new instances of `Entity` and assign them to the data source array. Further you need `DispatchGroup` to handle the loop and reload the table view after the last entity has been created.

If you want to overwrite `self.contents` with the received data uncomment the `removeAll` line

```
func APIcall() {
    
    ServerCommunicator.getPairs().done{ response in
     // self.contents.removeAll()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for keyPathParam in response {
            group.enter()
            ServerCommunicator.getPair(with: keyPathParam.name).done{ ticker in
               let entity = Entity(name: ticker.name, price: ticker.price, volume: ticker.volume)
               self.contents.append(entity)
               group.leave()
            }.catch{(err) in
                print(err)
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }.catch{(error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time, tips and effort.. I appreciate it..   let me test it then.. )

Comment: thanks for your help, I am happy to accept it as the correct answer.. i am sure it works, I tested it, it gave me the expected structure of the expected result.. however, the rest is the type mismatch in my own code structure, i am sure your logic works.. .

Comment: now, i am having one more issue, i guess this gonna be the last issue.. . if i could resolve it, i hope the solution is done for this issue once and forever.. .

Comment: the issue is `responseSerializationError`

Comment: cuz,  `// MARK: - TradingPairElement` returns an array where the `// MARK: - TickerByPair` returns just a simple `dictionary` and inside the `for loop` i guess something went wrong for the `apiCall` i guess..

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question. Ask a new one and provide all relevant information, not just the code. Describe the issue and where it occurs, the errors you get, and the actual and expected result. And if you use API that `throws` don't ignore the error with `try?`, always `catch` and print the `error`.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I will stick to it.. thanks.. I will post the next question, see you in the upcoming questions.. . lol )